# What does ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol mean?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, http-status-code-404, alpn

I see this quite regularly when using various calls in curl.

I'm not sure if its the root cause to some of my returns resulting in error 400 but as a newbie just curious more than anything.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the server does not support [ALPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation). For example, Debian 8.0 (with OpenSSL 1.0.1k) does only support NPN [2](https://www.nginx.com/blog/supporting-http2-google-chrome-users/). But Ubuntu 16.04 ship OpenSSL 1.0.2g, which support ALPN, so I'm not sure this is the issue.

I don't think it could cause HTTP 400 errors, except if the server enforce HTTP2.

Answer (score 0):

From [Craig Hicks](https://serverfault.com/users/436331/craig-hicks)'s excellent [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/921972/229708) to "["server certificate verification OK" but "ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol"](https://serverfault.com/q/920928/229708)":

> Exactly what this line
>
> `* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol`
>
> means is still a mystery, but I'm guessing it means either (1) not agreeing to HTTP/2, or less likely (2) the client asked if it continue without authorization and was refused, and thereupon used authorization. A truly bad choice of language for diagnostic output. Google returns thousands of results for that literal expression.

I did an HTTP2 test ([tools.keycdn.com/http2-test](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test) used in [HBruijn](https://serverfault.com/users/37681/hbruijn)'s [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/953900/229708) to a similar question) on a site that returned the same line, and got this:

```
HTTP/2 protocol is not supported.
ALPN extension is not supported.
```

I.e. it would seem that the `ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol` line may show up simply because the endpoint doesn't support ALPN ([Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation (ALPN) is a Transport Layer Security (TLS) extension for application layer protocol negotiation](https://serverfault.com/questions/920928/server-certificate-verification-ok-but-alpn-server-did-not-agree-to-a-protoc#:%7E:text=Application%2DLayer%20Protocol%20Negotiation%20(ALPN)%20is%20a%20Transport%20Layer%20Security%20(TLS)%20extension%20for%20application%20layer%20protocol%20negotiation)).