# HTTP/2 not enabled on a configured Apache 2.4.38 web server

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, http2

I have a Debian 10 (had the exact same issue with Debian 9) running an Apache 2.4.38 web server. Apache modules `mpm_event` and `http2` are installed and the websites are served through HTTPS.

I have added the http2 line in every Apache virtualhost conf file for each of my websites, like :

```
<VirtualHost *:12080>
    # HTTP2
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
    ...
```

EDIT: When I tested with web-based online tools, I got the answer "HTTP/2 protocol is not supported / ALPN extension is not supported".

When I curl one of my website (`curl -I -k https://mywebsite.com`), I have the following response, obviously still in HTTP/1.1:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 30 Jul 2019 03:14:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=7ulo4hj17ukek6s15g99fc2812; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: C00=; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
```

Did I forget something to have HTTP/2?

*In case, here is also the content of my `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/http2.conf` file:*

```
<IfModule !mpm_prefork>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: ALPN seems to be NOT enabled (don't know if that can be an explanation) and my OpenSSL version is 1.1.1c.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the port number?

Comment: Can you elaborate? (sites are successfully served through HTTPS / HTTP/1.1)

Comment: Your `<VirtualHost>` specifies the non-default port 12080, but your curl command did not.

Comment: Non standard port 12080 is used for SSL redirect but from the outside it doesn't change anything, doesn't it? Websites are successfully served without specifying the port number, but I can read HTTP/1.1 wether it is in curl response, keycdn.com's HTTP/2 web-based testing tool, or Google Chrome console when examining HTTP headers.

Comment: What do you mean by "SSL redirect but from the outside it doesn't change anything"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused since I didn't configured that part myself, but I guess it was done for SSL reasons, and it is redirected to standard 80 port. I will have a closer look though.

Answer (score 2):

The server header : `Upgrade: h2,h2c` shows that the HTTP/2 protocol **is** available server-side ...

The problem is your `curl` command line and the fact that http/2 is usually negotiated and not always used immediately

See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html

> curl offers the `--http2` command line option to enable use of HTTP/2.
>
> curl offers the `--http2-prior-knowledge` command line option to enable use of HTTP/2 without HTTP/1.1 Upgrade.

Comment: Do you mean, the `curl` command on the client side? I checked with `--http2` option, it's the same. Also, I should have said that I also tried web-based tools, not only curl, to test the HTTP/2, but it always says HTTP/2 is not available (I will edit my question to include that fact). Thanks to your answer I now tried `--http2-prior-knowledge` curl option, but I got this answer: `curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer`. I think this is still a problem server-side. I suspect something with ALPN/TLS.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/953900/37681 may be of interest

Comment: Thanks. I read something similar, but I'm actually running event MPM, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether the module is enabled on your server.

```
#cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/http2.load
```

Make sure the following line is there:

```
LoadModule http2_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_http2.so
```

`# apache2ctl -M | grep http2`  - If enabled, the Output similar to the following:
 `http2_module (shared)`

Comment: Thanks. `http2_module` seems enabled and loaded, output is exactly as you said.

Answer (score -1):

Did you enable the http2 Apache module and restart the Apache service?

`sudo a2enmod http2
sudo systemctl restart apache2`

reference: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-enable-http-2-in-apache/

Comment: Yes. It is running that way for several years actually, and has been restarted many times.